# Socket Programming Python Server and C client

Tags: python, sockets

this is what i make in python server code (receiving data length from C client and then receiving image file(.jpg))
but **problem** is when i receiving data length error occurs **"invaild base64-encoded string"**

here is my servercode (Removed unnecessary functions) and when trying to run the **stringData** part the error occurs

```
import os
import socket
import cv2
import numpy
import base64
import glob
import sys
import time
import threading
from datetime import datetime

class ServerSocket:

    def receiveImages(self):
        cnt_str = ''
        cnt = 0

        try:
            while True:
                if (cnt < 10):
                    cnt_str = '000' + str(cnt)
                elif (cnt < 100):
                    cnt_str = '00' + str(cnt)
                elif (cnt < 1000):
                    cnt_str = '0' + str(cnt)
                else:
                    cnt_str = str(cnt)
                if cnt == 0: startTime = time.localtime()
                cnt += 1

                length = self.conn.recv(64)
                print(length)
                length1 = length.decode('utf-8')
                print(length1)
        
                stringData = self.recvall(self.conn, int(length1))
               ## stringData = self.conn.recv(100000)
               ##print(stringData)

               msg = "ready"
                self.conn.sendall(msg.encode())

               stime = self.recvall(self.conn, 64)
               print('send time: ' + stime.decode('utf-8'))
                now = time.localtime()
               print('receive time: ' + datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

                data = numpy.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(stringData), numpy.uint8)
                decimg = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)
                cv2.imshow("image", decimg)
                cv2.imwrite('./' + str(self.TCP_PORT) + '_images' + str(self.folder_num) + '/img' + cnt_str + '.jpg', decimg)
                cv2.waitKey(1)

                if (cnt == 60 * 10):
                    cnt = 0
                    convertThread = threading.Thread(target=self.convertImage(str(self.folder_num), 600, startTime))
                    convertThread.start()
                    self.folder_num = (self.folder_num + 1) % 2


        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            #self.convertImage(str(self.folder_num), cnt, startTime)
            self.socketClose()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            self.socketOpen()
            self.receiveThread = threading.Thread(target=self.receiveImages)
            self.receiveThread.start()
        
    def recvall(self, sock, count):
        buf = b''
        while count:
            newbuf = sock.recv(count)
            if not newbuf: return None
            buf += newbuf
            count -= len(newbuf)
        return buf    

    def convertImage(self, fnum, count, now):
        img_array = []
        cnt = 0
        for filename in glob.glob('./' + str(self.TCP_PORT) + '_images' + fnum + '/*.jpg'):
            if (cnt == count):
                break
            cnt = cnt + 1
            img = cv2.imread(filename)
            height, width, layers = img.shape
            size = (width, height)
            img_array.append(img)
        
        file_date = self.getDate(now)
        file_time = self.getTime(now)
        name = 'video(' + file_date + ' ' + file_time + ').mp4'
        file_path = './videos/' + name
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(file_path, cv2.VideqqoWriter_fourcc(*'.mp4'), 20, size)

        for i in range(len(img_array)):
            out.write(img_array[i])
        out.release()
        print(u'complete')


def main():
    server = ServerSocket('ServerIP', PORT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

what could it be the problems? in my expectation when decode the string data it can be the problem that C client encode causes problem

Comment: of course it is hard to answer without the c code, can you be clearer when the exception occurs?  It it the data length line (`                length1 = length.decode('utf-8')`) or the base64 decode line (`base64.b64decode(stringData)` )  Is there a full exception or error message?

Comment: You should figure out if it's the client or server.  Don't tag both languages (i.e. remove c).  If it's the server, as it appears, then you need to provide us with the data to reproduce the issue.  nc, socat can be helpful tools for this.